# how should i run this in tensorflow 2.0?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, regression, keras-layer

I am trying to run this on python 3.7.6.
Even though I have the `tflearn` module the code throws the error "no module found".
Now I have installed Tensorflow 2.0, I want these to be coded using tf2.0 and keras.

```
net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, len(training[0])])
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 8)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 8)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, len(output[0]), activation="softmax")
net = tflearn.regression(net)
net = tflearn.DNN(net)
net.fit(training, output, n_epoch=1000, batch_size=8, show_metric=True)
net.save("model.tflearn")
```

Comment: Please do not only paste code. Read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) first, describe your problem in detail, what you already tried, etc.

Comment: now i have tried  explaining it. Thank you for correcting me. This is my very first question.

Comment: tflearn require tensorflow 1

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about tflearn but in tensorflow and keras it would look something like this-

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([ 
                                    tf.keras.layers.Dense(8, activation='relu',input_shape=[len(train_dataset.keys())]), 
                                    tf.keras.layers.Dense(8, activation='relu'), 
                           tf.keras.layers.Dense(len(output[0], activation='softmax')])
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam,
              loss = 'mse',
              metrics=['mse'])

model.fit(x, y, epochs=1000)
```

Comment: I am getting error . for the last output layer "**type error**": moudle object is not callable